# Efficient solution for Bike Tracker

Tags: electrical-engineering

there
I installed SINO 942 tracker in my bike, it works well, but then my bike's self start has stopped working (it works when I ride bike for around an hour), so
I think the tracker is eating up battery when the bike is parked for long hours.

I am already thinking about installing a manual switch, or a rechargable
12 V battery (so it wont need to connect to main battery), but all of these
are manual and regularly to-be-interacted-with solutions.

Please suggest best solution I can use to rectify this issue.

Comment: The trouble with asking for "what is best" is that what is best for you may not be the best for anyone else. Having a manual switch requires you to always remember to turn the switch on & off when required. A separate battery isolates the tracker from the main battery & you just have to replace the separate battery when it is flat or nearly flat. Having an additional battery will add more weight to the bike. Will this be a problem for you? Decide what will be the most convenient for you & do it.

Comment: Can you check with an ammeter to be sure how much current the SINO 942 is drawing while the bike is parked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with your second battery, but use a split-charge system so whenever the bike is running the second battery gets charged.

An example of a split charge system / relay is [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/160477-0-727-10-EQUIV-12V-100A-100-AMP-HEAVY-DUTY-SPLIT-CHARGE-RELAY-CAMPER-VAN/201605769301?hash=item2ef0a3e855:g:0f4AAOSwgsxaaEY8)